# Do Spark RDD tuple fields need to be serializable? Mahout Drm seems to say no

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mahout, rdd

Mahout's DrmRdd type is defined as

```
type DrmRdd[K] = RDD[DrmTuple[K]]
```

Which translates to

```
RDD[(K,Vector)]
```

However, Mahout documentation clearly states that the Vector class is not serializable.

This is leading me to some headscratching as to how to generate an RDD[(K,Vector)] to wrap into a Mahout Drm without tripping over the fact that Vector is not serializable.

My question is, when does a spark RDD tuple need to be serializable? Or do they only need to be serializable for certain functions that require them to be passed through a shuffle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, technically speaking if there is no reason to serialize (there is no shuffle, caching with serialization or similar process you can have RDD with data which is not serializable. For example if you have data like this:

```
class Foo(x: Int)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 4, 4).map(i => (i, new Foo(i)))
```

where `Foo` is not serializable you can count:

```
rdd.count
// 4
```

but you cannot `distinct.count`:

```
rdd.distinct.count
// java.io.NotSerializableException: $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Foo
// Serialization stack:
//  - object not serializable (class: $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Foo, value: ...
//  - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _2, type: class java.lang.Object)
//  - object (class scala.Tuple2, (1,$line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Foo@70accf6))
//  at ...
```

So non serializable objects are useful only for temporary storage limited to a single task.

But this is not the case with Mahout Vector. `Mahout` Spark bindings actually provide [Kryo registration tools](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/f115633fd4de83afd1be1cc8ced61580cc426604/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/mahout/sparkbindings/io/MahoutKryoRegistrator.scala) and `Vector` [is actually registered there](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/f115633fd4de83afd1be1cc8ced61580cc426604/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/mahout/sparkbindings/io/MahoutKryoRegistrator.scala#L35):

```
kryo.addDefaultSerializer(classOf[Vector], new VectorKryoSerializer())
```

and provides [specialized serializer](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/f115633fd4de83afd1be1cc8ced61580cc426604/math-scala/src/main/scala/org/apache/mahout/common/io/VectorKryoSerializer.scala)

Also please note that Kryo can be significantly more forgiving so when you set `spark.serializer` to `org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer` `distinct.count` example provided above will work just fine even though `Foo` is not serializable using Java serialization.

Comment: Ahhh Kryo registration for serialization! Reason why I was worried was because Spark 1.6 added an explicit check for serializability of tuple fields in shuffle ops via org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable, for which all Vectors fail, e.g.: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector. But if they're actually serializable since Kryo is always present via Spark config, I can just mixin Serializable safely and remove the exception.

Comment: I should be more specific - the operation used here is aggregateByKey, which takes a zero value of the value type for aggregation. It is part of the closure to the aggregation functions, which is why Spark throws even though it is kryo-serializable, since all closure elements must be java serializable. The solution is a little trickier than just mixing in Serializable.

Comment: If this is an issue there are different workarounds. You could for  example use `combineByKey`. Also breeze vectors are serializable and don't require external deps.